# How to capture all caps words for textual analysis using excel?

Tags: excel, analysis, textual

I'm currently working with a large dataset based on people's reviews. The dataset includes 25 thousand individuals' reviews of different books, and each row on the text column is unique and has lots of sentences.

My issue is that I'd like to code for whether the text contains any ALL CAPS words. For instance, someone could say: "This book is AMAZING! I loved it!." Normally, excel allows you to directly identify when the cell is entirely written in all caps, but this situation is a bit more unique than that, given that I want to be able to see whether any word within the text is written in all caps. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I googled possible solutions, and also ask ChatGPT3.5 and GPT4. Nothing that came out gave me an implementable suggestion (GPT was giving codes that were too long for excel to carry out, and the shorter ones it gave were plain wrong)

Comment: What about `I` in your example?, strictly speaking, it is a word.

Comment: Do you want to capture the actual uppercase words (as per title) or you want to get a false/true result if any all-caps word exist? Please tell us more about possible edge-cases too. What about 'Hello,WORLD!'. There is no space to split on, but would punctuation marks be considered word-boundaries?

Comment: @JvdV this is a great question, thanks for asking for clarification on this one. To answer them:

1) My priority is to be able to categorize whether the review contains all cap words. I do not need to word per se, a true/false function would be enough.

2) Great catch on the edge-cases. Yes, some people will not be too careful when writing, which may then result in cases such as "Hello,WORLD." If it is possible to catch these cases based on the punctuation mark, I'd definitely want to do that.

Comment: @DavidLeal yes, you are right in the strictest sense of how all caps would work. However, given that "I" type statements would be an accepted case of how we write normally, I would not categorize the word as an 'all cap.' So, I suppose the more specific way of asking the question is how do we find all caps words that are longer than just 1 character

Comment: @DesperateinStatistics I updated my answer considering the comments you provided here, please check and let me know. Thanks

Comment: Right @DesperateinStatistics, we can start to see where this is going. Next problem: what if there is a brand or product, or a simple product number like 'CTE7005GY4'. I think you need to narrow down what to you is a word in all caps. No numbers included? Allow certain keywords or not? Etc. My thoughts are shifting towards regular expressions

Comment: @JVdV you're raising some very important points here. Given the sheer number of reviews I have, I didn't think about all the details that should be considered here. For instance, people can write company names in all caps (e.g., "MGM made a movie about this book.") This doesn't mean they are choosing to write a word in all caps themselves, they're just writing the company name. Same thing would happen if I wrote the name of a stock ticker. So, I assume this makes it almost impossible to create a holistic approach to finding out all cap words (in the way I'm defining them?)

Comment: @DesperateinStatistics exactly my point. Unless, and only if you are able to check each word that is written in all caps against a list of rules that apply if a word is intentionally written in all caps, you'd find yourself stuck with an immense probability of finding false positives and thus a false outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can put your data into a Table in Excel you can utilise PowerQuery to do this pretty easily, using some dummy data as shown below.

Select a cell in your table then go to Data => Get &Transform Data => From Table.Range

[image]

This will load up the Power Query editor and if you go to Add Column => Custom Column and enter the following it'll add a True/False column that indicates if there's any capital words for each row
[image]

[image]

[image]

Then go to File => Close & Load To...
[image]

and choose to load it to a Table on a new or existing sheet and it'll give you the data
[image]
[image]

The HasCaps code works by splitting the text column at every space " " and creating a list, it then checks if each item in that list is the same when you capitalise it, and then checks if there are any 'trues' in the list.

Comment: Thank you for this! I really appreciate all the screenshots for guidance. I wanted to use this on my data, however my excel does not seem to have From Table/Range function in there. I only have "Get Data (Power Query)" and right next to it "From Picture." I also looked at the details of Get Data area, and none of the options map onto from table/range. When i do use the Get Data area, it also does not pop up an "Add column" either. Is this because I am using Mac? Would trying Windows make it better?

Comment: Ahh, ok the Power Query functionality in Excel for Mac is pretty limited, though the ‘Insiders’ edition/version of Excel for Mac is more complete (see https://insider.office.com/ro-ro/blog/shape-data-with-power-query-editor-in-excel-for-mac), though it might need some slightly different steps (ultimately the PQ script would be the same but the UI might be different). Best bet would be windows but could possibly get it working on Mac

Comment: Also re the comments in the formula based answer, PQ (in Windows at least) can also easily handle the exclusion of single character Caps or strings with Caps and numbers very easily as well, happy to add some info on how to do this as well if you wanted to go down the PQ path

Comment: That would be awesome. I really don't know what I'm doing, so I very much appreciate the help with eliminating numbers and single character words from this. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following, assuming your input data is in cell `A1` and considering also additional conditions indicated in the comment section of the question: 1) Exclude words with length equal to 1, 2) Consider as word delimiter `,` too:

```
=LET(s,TEXTSPLIT(A1,{" ",","}), f, FILTER(s,(LEN(s) >1) 
 * EXACT(s, UPPER(s)),""), IF(@f="", FALSE, TRUE))
```

It can be encapsulated in a user `LAMBDA` function `Z`, so you can use it for array ranges.

```
=LET(A, A1:A4, Z, LAMBDA(x, LET(s,TEXTSPLIT(x,{" ",","}),
 f, FILTER(s,(LEN(s) >1) * EXACT(s, UPPER(s)),""), IF(@f="", FALSE, TRUE))),
 BYROW(A, LAMBDA(x, Z(x))))
```

Here is the output:

[image: output]

It identifies the word by   or `,` delimiters, then uses the `EXACT` function to do case sensitive comparisons.

Keep in mind that if you have `AMAZING01` it considers this case as valid too. If you want to exclude it, you need to define the list of allowed characters (`lk`) and check that only such characters can appear. For example for upper case letters exclamation sign and punctuation only, you can consider the following:

```
=LET(lk, VSTACK(CHAR(ROW(65:90)), "!",".", ";"), s,TEXTSPLIT(A1,{" ",","}), 
 f, FILTER(s,(LEN(s) >1) * EXACT(s, UPPER(s))
  * ISERR(TEXTSPLIT(s, lk,,1)),""), IF(@f="", FALSE, TRUE))
```

You can check here the list of [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters and add the ones you consider in a similar way. You can use `CHAR(33)` instead of `"!"` for example. It makes sense to use the function in case you can find a range of valid consecutive values from the ASCII list of characters.

The expression: `TEXTSPLIT(s, lk,,1)` extracts from `s` name on each cell everything that is not a valid character and produce an error of type `Empty Array` (`#CALC!`) when all characters are valid and this the condition we are looking for.